# PHP preg_match for getting a string part after the given optional substrings

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have several urls such as below and those contains `-XX-` letter and following `xxxxxxxxx` key in the end of the url.

```
http://vayes-eys.dev/shoe-for-ladies/high-hields/7-pont-with-silver-stripes-PD-0a8564q56
```

or

```
http://vayes-eys.dev/news/europe/england/cricket-news/josh-darpant-is-on-the-way-to-rome-NS-e3q3s2wq4q
```

What I want to do is; first to check if `-NS-`, `-PD-` or `-SP-` exist in url, then get the `-XX-` part and the part after it,for example: `e3q3s2wq4q`.

What I have done so far is:

```
$path = "shoe-for-ladies/high-hields/7-pont-with-silver-stripes-PD-0a8564q56"

if (preg_match('/-PD-|-NS-|-SP-/',$path)) {
    preg_match("/(?<=(-PD-|-NS-|-SP-)).*/", $path, $match);
    print_r($match);
}
```

This gives me the following array but I am not sure if it is the right way.

```
array(
    0 => 0a8564q56
    1 => -PD-
)
```

What I need is `PD` and `0a8564q56`. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use [`-(NS|PD|SP)-(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/bM7kF1/1) in `preg_match_all` use both captured groups.

Comment: Why the 2 `preg_match`s. Just put the second one in the conditional.

Comment: There's no need to use `preg_match` twice, build a pattern with capture groups to extract informations you want.

Comment: @anubhava `if(preg_match_all('/-(NS|PD|SP)-(\w+)/', $path, $match)) { print_r($match); }` working nicely. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
'~-(NS|PD|SP)-([^-/]+)~'
```

or

```
'~-(NS|PD|SP)-([A-Za-z0-9]+)~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vC2fI1/1)

**Details**:

- `-` - a literal hyphen
- `(NS|PD|SP)` - Group 1 capturing one of the values: `NS`, `PD` or `SP`
- `-`  - a hyphen
- `([^-/]+)`  - 1 or more characters other than `-` and `/` (the delimiters). If you only have letters and digits there, you may just use `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` instead.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/0neCLn):

```
$path = "shoe-for-ladies/high-hields/7-pont-with-silver-stripes-PD-0a8564q56";
preg_match('~-(NS|PD|SP)-([A-Za-z0-9]+)~', $path, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Your values are in Group 1 and 2.

Comment: Stribizew, I works nicely, Thank you. Two question: One of the friends here suggested `(\w+)` for the second group. What's difference with your `([^-/]+)`..

Comment: Maybe one more, if you have time. Can we get also the part before -NS- at the same preg_match?

Comment: Is that part optional?  What should it look like if you have the input as in my code snippet? `7-pont-with-silver-stripes` or `stripes`?

Comment: @YahyaE You can use the regex101 provided link to alter the regex and see how it functions with the alterations. Here's an update with the `\w+` https://regex101.com/r/vC2fI1/2. The site also provides a description of each part on the right side. `\w+` is any alpha character, number, or under score. `[^-/]+` is any non `-` or `-`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That part is not optional. `http://abc.ltd/<group1>-<NS|PD>-<group3>` or `http://abc.ltd/sth/smw/smo/<last-segment>-<NS|PD>-<group3>`. I can use both.